# VSFTP permissions issues

Tags: ftp

Having a strage issues with VSFTP at the moment whereby the folder is has been chowned and chmodded like so:

```
drw-rw----  2 james   staff    4096 Aug 10 20:52 folder
```

So the user and group has read and write access. The VSFTP conf looks like so:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=FTP Server
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_max_port=65535
pasv_min_port=64000
chroot_local_user=YES

dual_log_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
syslog_enable=NO
```

However, I cant even browse the folder nor write despite the fact I should be able to. I I however, I chmod it to 770 then I can read and write fine, however, 660 is preferred given execution is not required. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To traverse a directory, it must have the executable bit set.  This is how filesystem permissions work in UNIX.

`770` would be the appropriate permissions if you wanted to allow the group write access as well.

Answer (score 0):

did you try : file_open_mode ?

file_open_mode
The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are applied on top of this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you want uploaded files to be executable.

(looks like the directory does not have x permission .. which is why you are not able to CD into the dir)

Comment: Your advice is dangerous.  Public writable should almost never been enabled except in special cases, such as with /tmp.

Comment: that is from default manual. (I should have formatted it better)

Answer (score 0):

You can't able to change the directory because you don't put the execute permission on it. Always remember that folder always execute when ever you change the directory if that directory doesn't have execute permission then you are not able to change that directory.

For vsftpd configuration reference [click here](http://www.rootlocker.com/complete-configuration-vsftpd-server-access-control-implementation/)